# Behavior of shapeless .toHList

Tags: scala, shapeless

The following compiles:

```scala
 object Run1 extends App {

  import shapeless._
  import syntax.std.traversable._

  case class Container[T](x: T)

  Seq(Container(1), Container("x")).toHList[Container[Int] :: Container[String] :: HNil]

}
```

But this does not:

```scala
object Run2 extends App {

  import shapeless._
  import syntax.std.traversable._

  class Container[T](val x: T)

  Seq(new Container(1), new Container("x")).toHList[Container[Int] :: Container[String] :: HNil]

}
```

It fails with the following errors:

```
Error:(40, 52) could not find implicit value for parameter fl: shapeless.ops.traversable.FromTraversable[shapeless.::    [com.adaje.service.table.Run2.Container[Int],shapeless.::[com.adaje.service.table.Run2.Container[String],shapeless.HNil]]]
Seq(new Container(1), new Container("x")).toHList[Container[Int] :: Container[String] :: HNil]
                                               ^
```

Why does the second program not work and is there anything that can be added so that it does?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FromTraversable` type class requires `Typeable` instances for the element types. Shapeless provides these off the shelf for case classes, but not for arbitrarily defined classes. You can define your own pretty easily, though:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.syntax.std.traversable._

class Container[T](val x: T)

implicit def containerTypeable[A: Typeable]: Typeable[Container[A]] =
  new Typeable[Container[A]] {
    def cast(t: Any): Option[Container[A]] = t match {
      case c: Container[_] => Typeable[A].cast(c.x).map(new Container(_))
      case _ => None
    }

    def describe: String = s"Container[${ Typeable[A].describe }]"
  }
```

And then:

```
scala> val cs = Seq(new Container(1), new Container("x"))
cs: Seq[Container[_ >: String with Int]] = List(Container@3c3c89b2, Container@1273a053)

scala> cs.toHList[Container[Int] :: Container[String] :: HNil]
res0: Option[shapeless.::[Container[Int],shapeless.::[Container[String],shapeless.HNil]]] = Some(Container@357c808b :: Container@607bcaf5 :: HNil)
```

And also:

```
scala> cs.reverse.toHList[Container[Int] :: Container[String] :: HNil]
res1: Option[shapeless.::[Container[Int],shapeless.::[Container[String],shapeless.HNil]]] = None
```

scalac's `-Xlog-implicits` option can be handy in cases like this—it'll make it clear that what was missing in your original non-case-class attempt was the `Typeable` instances.